# Detecting Windows Physical Console Logon

Tags: windows, active-directory, logging, windows-event-log, audit

I'm trying to find a way to detect a logon where someone is physically at the machine. I know you can do it with Type 2 but the issue is that events get logged when services make a logon request such as when someone logs on through a service.

One way I found that might be accurate is when Source Network Address shows a local IP like 127.0.0.1

Is this accurate enough or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the following log:

`Applications and Services Logs`/ `Microsoft` / `Windows` / `TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager` / [...]`Operational`

**Event ID 21** *Remote Desktop Services: Session logon succeeded* (with `LOCAL` in "Address").

[image: XML representation of Event ID 21]

**Event ID 25** *Remote Desktop Services: Session reconnection succeeded* may be interesting too, typically if someone connects remotely first and then reconnect from the local computer (with `LOCAL` in "Address" too).

[image: XML representation of Event ID 25]

However, keep in mind that if someone remote controls the computer with a third-party tool for example, and logs on afterwards Windows will not be able to detect this as a remote connection of course.